# javascript UI components making too many http request. Any idea how to optimize this?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

This question is purely based on assumptions. May or may not be valid problem. Anyway, here it goes

Let's say we have a heavy javascript client app with some numbers 
of UI components / widgets, Each of these widgets has 
an endpoint to query data from

On a page load, these components will make http request. 
Multiple of them; to multiple different endpoints.

Obviously we see that the number of http requests will increase 
with heavy client side architecture as compared to traditional web where 
UI is generated from the server side.

Sample case:

- widget A requests resource A
- widget B requests resource B

Of course, we can minimize the http request by having:

- parent widget requests an endpoint that return { resource A, resource B }
- parent widget distributes data to widget A
- parent widget distributes data to widget B

This can be done by, sort of, grouping related widgets based on business logic

Not all can be framed this way. Even if it can, how would maintain code modularity? 
Is there any well known design pattern for large javascript apps wrt. performance? 
Maybe I am overthinking as I certainly dont have the numbers here.
Any thought guys?

Comment: Indenting each line is what causes the question to look like that - that's how you quote **code**.

Comment: I unindented for dvliman to make it easier on the eyes to read

Comment: eh didn't mean to put it on the code block. I just want to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

for starters I would consider creating a client JavaScript library that would handle fetching/sending data and make all the widgets use this API.

this way you can optimize/group the flow of data to/from all of your widgets in one place.

Answer (score 0):

One idea that comes to mind (which wouldn't reduce the amount of data transferred, but would reduce the number of HTTP requests) is to route all your AJAX requests on the client side through some common Javascript interface that you control.

Then, instead of sending out one HTTP request per UI request, you can wait a few milliseconds and batch all the requests that occur within that interval, sending out just one HTTP request for the whole batch (you'd have to be careful to only do this for requests going to your server).

On the server, you could have a special generic "batched" endpoint that internally services all the batched requests (preferably in parallel) and returns the results in a batched response.

Then the client side distributes the batched results to the original requesters.

Note that this only works if the requests all take approximately the same length of time to service; you wouldn't want the batched response waiting 30s for one sub-request to finish when all the others are already done. You might be able to address this with a blacklist or something.

Also, try to identify which requests need to be serviced first and assign them priority!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is a central queue for all the data requests.  Each widget on it's own can make requests by queuing up a specific request.  Then, you would have a common piece of code that examines all the requests in the queue and figures out if they can be optimized a bit (requesting multiple pieces of data in one request from the same endpoint).

Using this type of design pattern still keeps all the widgets modular, yet has one small library of code that handles the optimization of the requests.

Technically, how this would work is that you'd create a library function for adding a request to the queue.  That function would require an endpoint, a callback function when the data is ready and a description of the request.  Each widget would call this common function for making it's data request.

This common function would put each request into a queue and then do a `setTimeout()` for 0ms (if one wasn't already set).  That `setTimeout()` will be called when the current thread of execution is done which will be when all requests for this current thread of initialization are now in the queue.  The queue can then be examined and any requests to the same endpoint that can be combined into one request and the request can be sent.  When the data arrives, the separate pieces of data are then parceled out and the appropriate widget's callback is called.

If caching of data would be helpful (if multiple requests over time for the exact same data are happening), this layer could also implement a cache.